# Should a bad USB device be able to crash a bug free Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, usb

My question is rather broad, I know, but I have been wondering about this for a long time.

A little background. I work in a Physics lab where all the lab computers are running Debian (mix of old version and Lenny) or more recently Ubuntu 10.4 LTS. We have written a lot of custom software to interface with experiment hardware and other computers.

We have a lot of FPGA boards that are controlling various parts of the experiment, these are connected via USB to different computers. After upgrading a computer controlling an experiment we started seeing crashes/lockups of the computer running all the lasers. This used to be completely stable.

My question is this: If the entire computer locks up because of an issue with
a) Python/GTK software gui
b) USB device driver
or
c) The actual device
can this be blamed on the Linux kernel (or other levels of the OS)?

Is it unfair to ask of the linux kernel not to panic even if I make mistakes in my implementation of software/hardware.

My own guess: Any user level applications should never be able to crash the entire system since they should only have access to their own stuff.

Any device driver becomes a part of the kernel itself and will therefore be able to crash it. Is my reasoning sound?

Bonus question: IS there a way to insulate device and kernel somehow such that Linux will keep running happily no matter what stupid mistakes are made with the hardware. That would be very useful for two reasons:
1) debugging is easier with a running system,
2) For the purposes of the experiment we really need long uptimes and having only a part of the system crash is infinitely better than crashes in one part of the system propagating to the rest.

Any links and reading material on this subject would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm no expert in crashes, but I'd say that you are right in your guesses. About the bonus question, _logical_ errors (ie. bad protocol) should be coped by the kernel with no further problems; but _phisical_ errors (ie. shortcircuit, overcurrent, etc.) cannot be, in general, be managed by the kernel, and will provoke different levels of disaster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that unprivileged code should not be able to bring down the system, unless there's a kernel bug.  The line between unprivileged and privileged isn't exactly the same as user-space vs kernel, however.  A user-mode program can open `/dev/kmem` and trash the OS's internal data structures, if the user account has superuser privileges.

To insulate the main kernel from device driver problems, run the device driver inside a virtual machine.

Several popular VM systems, including VMWare Workstation, support forwarding an arbitrary USB device from the host to the guest without a device-specific driver on the host.

Comment: Follow up question. Assuming the device driver was written correctly any hardware failure (of the attached device) should not be able to bring the system down, correct?

Comment: @HansHarhoff: As long as the failed hardware doesn't cause the maximum allowable tolerances specified for the computer port where it's attached to be violated, that's correct.  Most USB hosts are tolerant of short circuits, for example.  On the other hand, if you have a lightning strike jump to a USB cable, all bets are off because the maximum ratings will be exceeded.

Comment: My two main concerns are as you say short circuits of the USB port (or at least voltage drops) and accidental/sudden disconnecting of hardware. We are about to test whether powered USB Hubs could work as a buffer for the short circuit.

With regards to sudden removal I guess the important things is to have some time out when waiting for reply.

Comment: @HansHarhoff: Because the device has a pull-up resistor on one of the data lines (either D+ or D-, depending on speed), it is possible for the host to detect sudden removal without resorting to a timeout.  Quality USB circuitry should not only survive short-circuit and sudden disconnect without damage, it should report it to software.  But not all manufacturers implement the logic functions for this, and not all drivers check for it.  If you aren't sure whether your USB host circuit is protected against overcurrent then a USB hub is a good way to contain the failure.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Even on devices which protect against damaged from over-current conditions, it is common to have multiple USB ports fed through the same power-supply circuitry, so excessive current draw from one device may disrupt operation of other devices fed by the same circuitry.

Comment: @supercat: Correct.  You wouldn't want to have an unreliable device sharing power regulation circuits (it's the point of regulation, not the shared supply, that will cause other devices difficulty during a short-circuit on one port) with for example your root / system partition.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Problems may occur with the point of regulation or supply.  If a supply has inadequate capacity to supply maximum current to all ports simultaneously, it may tell ports how much power they're allowed to use, and shut off ports that draw too much, but if the supply is fully loaded when a device that's requested 10mA starts drawing 2000mA, it may not be able to cut off the device before it causes a voltage sag on other devices.

Comment: @supercat: A desktop power supply that can provide >50A to the CPU and similar currents to GPUs and disk drives does not much care about USB pulling 2A instead of 0.1A.  In an embedded system the supply might be less robust, but typically the local regulator will be designed not to overload the supply and instead shut off (affecting all devices sharing the regulator).  Having multiple devices affected by the overcurrent protection is a legitimate concern, overloading the supply is not (as that can only happen with a seriously defective design).

Comment: @BenVoigt: For a main-system supply, I would generally agree, but something like a Raspberry Pi may be powered by a device whose limits the Pi's designers would have no way of knowing.  Further, my main point had to do with the possibility of USB devices interfering with each other.  If the system is performing some critical task using a drive that's plugged into the same bus-powered hub as an untrustworthy device, that task could be disrupted if the untrustworthy device draws too much current.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed.  When I said "a USB hub is a good way to contain the failure", I meant that the hub will keep the failure from affecting upstream.  Not that it will protect other devices connected downstream of the same hub.  I was replying to [a mention of a self-powered hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162657/should-a-bad-usb-device-be-able-to-crash-a-bug-free-linux-kernel/10164327?noredirect=1#comment13060030_10164327), not a bus-powered one. And note that in this question, we are talking about a desktop computer which ought to have a power supply greatly exceeding USB demands.